# Expanding div on hover relative to a parent div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a parent div with a few children:

```html
<div id="main">
   <div id="child1">
      <div id="child2">
         <div id="child3">content</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```css
#main {width: 700px;}
#child1 {width: 150px;}
#child2 {width: 100%;}
#child3 {width: 100%;}
```

On hover, I want **#child3** to expand to 90% width of **#main**, not be constrained to the 150px of its parent.

I tried giving **#child3** a fixed width in px, but that caused a lot of issues with content spilling outside the **#main** div. I want to keep the expanded content of **#child3** inside **#main** at all times.

Can this be done with JavaScript or jQuery? Please advise. Thanks!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tcpwL5z/) here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? What errors do you get with your code? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I will put a JSFiddle, I understand. Regarding your question, what I tried is only to give it a width in pixels, like I said in my post. Nothing else. I only read about the possibility to append CSS dinamically using jQuery.

Comment: Yes, that can be done with the `.css()` option. But I also don't know how you setup your `.hover()` or what should happen when the User moves away from the element.

Comment: I added the JSFiddle. When the user moves away, #child3 should return to its original position. Please look at the JSFiddle, thanks!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70964312/edit) to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#child3").hover(function() {
    // In
    $(this).css("width", $("#main").width() * 0.9);
  }, function() {
    // Out
    $(this).css("width", "");
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  width: 700px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

#child1 {
  width: 150px;
}

#child2 {
  width: 100%;
}

#child3 {
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #c00;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="child1">
    <div id="child2">
      <div id="child3">content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `.hover()`, `.css()`, `.width()` you can calculate a new width that is 90% the width of another element. You can assign this and then re-assign it after.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/hover/
- https://api.jquery.com/css/
- https://api.jquery.com/width/